# Change colorpicker for nicedit.js to photoshop like

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, color-picker, nicedit

I want to change the default color picker for nicedit.js
While going through the js file, I can see that the below code is generating the color-picker. Data is set up using `colorList` variable. Can anyone please help me to get a color-picker like photoshop or more relavant.

```
var nicEditorColorButton = nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({ 
  addPane : function() {
      var colorList = {0 : '00',1 : '33',2 : '66',3 :'99',4 : 'CC',5 : 'FF'};
      var colorItems = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({width: '270px'});

      for(var r in colorList) {
        for(var b in colorList) {
          for(var g in colorList) {
            var colorCode = '#'+colorList[r]+colorList[g]+colorList[b];

            var colorSquare = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({'cursor' : 'pointer', 'height' : '15px', 'float' : 'left'}).appendTo(colorItems);
            var colorBorder = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({border: '2px solid '+colorCode}).appendTo(colorSquare);
            var colorInner = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({backgroundColor : colorCode, overflow : 'hidden', width : '11px', height : '11px'}).addEvent('click',this.colorSelect.closure(this,colorCode)).addEvent('mouseover',this.on.closure(this,colorBorder)).addEvent('mouseout',this.off.closure(this,colorBorder,colorCode)).appendTo(colorBorder);

            if(!window.opera) {
              colorSquare.onmousedown = colorInner.onmousedown = bkLib.cancelEvent;
            }

          } 
        } 
      }
      this.pane.append(colorItems.noSelect());  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the colorList to array containing photoshop hex values and then use it like this:

```
var nicEditorColorButton = nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({ 
  addPane : function() {
  var colorList = {0 : '000000',1 : 'FFFFFF'};  /* here goes color list */
  var colorItems = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({width: '270px'});

  for(var g in colorList) {
    var colorCode = '#'+colorList[g];
    var colorSquare = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({'cursor' : 'pointer', 'height' : '15px', 'float' : 'left'}).appendTo(colorItems);
    var colorBorder = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({border: '2px solid '+colorCode}).appendTo(colorSquare);
    var colorInner = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({backgroundColor : colorCode, overflow : 'hidden', width : '11px', height : '11px'}).addEvent('click',this.colorSelect.closure(this,colorCode)).addEvent('mouseover',this.on.closure(this,colorBorder)).addEvent('mouseout',this.off.closure(this,colorBorder,colorCode)).appendTo(colorBorder);

    if(!window.opera) {
      colorSquare.onmousedown = colorInner.onmousedown = bkLib.cancelEvent;
    }

  }
  this.pane.append(colorItems.noSelect());  
}});
```

Not sure if my code is edited correctly but you get the basic idea. Remove 2 for loops and loop within the colorList directly